# Grails 3 on tomcat 8 : Domain classes can not cast themself

Tags: java, tomcat, grails, casting, tomcat8

I have a grails 3 application that works on local. But, when I create a war file (with `grails war` or `grails package`) and deploy on tomcat 8 (8.5.5). I have an error.

```
Class org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException
Message : converter found capable of converting from type [Player] to type [Player]
```

This error has no sense for me. But this exception is thrown when it execute this kind of code :

```
    def players = Player.all
    players.sort(new Comparator() {
        @Override
        int compare(o1, o2) {
            int p1followers = User.findAllByPlayer(o1).size()
            int p2followers = User.findAllByPlayer(o2).size()
            return p1followers > p2followers ? 1 : p1followers == p2followers ? 0 : -1
        }
    })
```

And every times I try to "cast" a Player to Player... Same with User,...

If I do :

```
List users = User.all
for(User u : users){}
```

I'll have a exception : "User can not be cast to User".

Here the User and Player domain class (I removed some parts)

```
class User {

static mapping = {
    table "users"
    /* ... */
}

/*...*/

static hasMany = [players : Player]

static constraints = {
     /* ... */
}
}`

class Player {

static mapping = {
    table "players"
    version:false
    /*...*/
}

/*...*/

static constraints = {
}
}
```

And this code works when I run the grails app in intelijIDEA but not when I deploy with the war file on tomcat 8.

And in my build.graddle I put this on provided :

```
//compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
provided "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
```

If you need more code, tell me and I edit.

Thanks.

Comment: Which exactly version of grails 3 are you using? Did you try to download tomcat on localhost and run war on it to exclude misconfiguration of production tomcat?

Comment: I'm using grails 3.1.3. And I'll try to run on a tomcat on localhost.

Comment: Off-topic comment: that comparator code appears to be hideously inefficient.

Comment: You should have the same tomcat and grails version locally (while creating a war file)  and on server and even jdk.

Comment: I tried on a tomcat locally and I have the same issue. The project works only with the command "grails run-app".